# ¿Por qué no se agrega el valor con este form a PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Estoy usando una imagen que al presionarla agregue un valor a mysqli, pero no entiendo por qué no funciona, al principio, creí que era porque tenía que ser un input tipo submit pero al cambiarlo tampoco funcionó, ya no tengo más ideas. ¿Me ayudan? gracias...

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['like'])){
 $sql2 = "UPDATE posts SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE titulo = '".$titulo."'";
 $query2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
  if($query2){

   }

} 
    <form method="post"><input style="position: fixed; top:10%; left:1.5%;width: 5%;" type="image" src="images/like.png" name="like"></form>
```

Comment: La variable $titulo, de donde la obtienes?, talves es eso, que la condicion where siempre es titulo = '', por eso nunca actualiza ningun registro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para empesar un input tipo submit o imagen nunca se mandan como post,

el imagen es para poner una imagen
El submit es para mandar el formulario

Lo que debes de hacer a tu input imagen ponerle un evento para que se mande al darle click

```
<input style="position: fixed; top:10%; left:1.5%;width: 5%;" type="image" src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ym/r/N2Pc61w97eJ.png" onclick="this.form.submit()">
```

Despues en el mismo formulario pon otro input oculto ( para que no se vea ) llamado like, que es el que llegara como post

```
<input type="hidden" name="like" value="SI" >
```

Al final te debe de quedar algo asi

```html
<form method="post">
 <input style="position: fixed; top:10%; left:1.5%;width: 5%;" type="image" src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ym/r/N2Pc61w97eJ.png"  onclick="this.form.submit()">
 <input type="hidden" name="like" value="SI" >
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias, me  sirvió

Answer (score 1):

principalmente porque no estas cerrando las etiqutedas de PHP, solo tienes la de apertura `<?php` pero no pusiste la de cierre. Otra observacion que tuve es que deberias de hacer tu php en un archivo externo, y cuando hagas tu form en html, agrega la el atributo action para que cuando se ejecute el codigo sepa que tiene que trabajar con el archivo php. Te quedaria algo asi:

```
<form action="archivo.php" method="post">
```